Cannot paste into SE code blocks when Editing, breaks text editor and Markdown preview
There seems to be something wrong with the text editor when editing code inside ``` code blocks. I've noticed this when editing questions.

Copy code from my IDE
Edit a question
Highlight all of the text inside an existing code block.
Press CMD-V to replace all of the existing code with the new version from my IDE.

Result:
All text is deleted. No text is pasted. Cannot press CMD-Z to "undo". Cannot type anything.
In order to type anything, I need to somehow break out of the code block by deleting backticks or typing newlines.

Test code formatting block (press Edit then try to replace all of this text). It works fine to type letters in/after each line, but not paste over the entire thing.
struct Foo {
    let string: String
}

blank code block (edit this question then try to type on that blank line)


When editing the blank code block above, typing the keys asdf results in nothing showing in the text edit area. The Markdown PREVIEW shows a single character which is then replaced in-place by each next individual character: a s d f.
macOS 14.2.1, Safari 17.2.1

The version of Safari which you are using is not supported. The current minimum supported version is 17.3. I don't know if that is the reason for the issues you are experiencing, but there are definitely issues with using the sites with older versions of Safari.

Strange. Fixed now after updating to macOS 14.4.1 and Safari 17.4.1. Would not expect that bug in a minor browser version update.
